# How to pass three arguments to django templatetags filter?

Tags: django

I know how to pass two parameters in template tag filter in Django but bit confused how to use 3 parameters.

My template tags-

```
@register.filter("status_of_booking")
def status_of_booking(status,create_date,from_time):
    print create_date
    print status
    return 'hola'
```

and i am passing three arguments like this and it is showing error:-

```
{{ item.status|status_of_booking:item.classSession.date,item.id }}
```

and the error it shows:
`status_of_booking requires 3 arguments, 2 provided`

Comment: What is the filter actually supposed to do? There's probably a better way to write it that doesn't require three arguments.

Comment: well i will compare my created_date and from_time  with current_date and then on the basis of status whether it will return or flase i  will return booking status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Django template filter takes either zero or one arguments. Multiple arguments are not possible.

In your case, you could use `item` as the first argument, instead of `status`:

```
@register.filter("status_of_booking")
def status_of_booking(item):
    print item.create_date
    print item.status
    return 'hola'
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ item|status_of_booking }}
```

If you really need multiple arguments, then you would have to change `status_of_booking` from a filter to a template tag,

```
@register.simple_tag
def status_of_booking(status, create_date, from_time):
    print create_date
    print status
    return 'hola'
```

and change your template to:

```
{% status_of_booking item.status item.classSession.date item.id %}
```