# Django template tags filter with multiple arguments

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-templates

Django template tags filter with multiple arguments

```
@register.filter
def customTag(value, first, second):
...
return result
```

Template

```
{{ valor|customTag:first|customTag:second }}
```

Error

> customTag requires 3 arguments, 2 provided

Comment: ...and the question is..?

Comment: Error customTag requires 3 arguments, 2 provided

Answer (score 9):

You can't pass multiple arguments to a filter([reference](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1199)). Instead, you can do it like this:

```
@register.filter
def customTag(value, args):
   first, second = args.split(',')
   ...
   return value

{{ valor|customTag:"first,second"}}  // pass comma separated arguments in string
```

Comment: What if you cannot coherence `arg` into a str so easliy? E.g. if it is a list from an `obj.mylist`?

Answer (score 2):

I had this doubt too.
I got a good result using {% with as %} in django template, but I needed to create two filters template tags:

Template tags:

```
@register.filter
def customTag(value, first):
...
return result1

@register.filter
def customTag2(first, second):
...
return result2
```

Template html:

```
{% with value|custom_tag:first as r1%}
    {% with r1|custom_tag2:second as r2 %}
        use your r2 value: {{ r2 }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just passing whole `customTag` instead of argument may solve the problem. Perhaps there are other possible solution possible.

```
@register.filter("filter_of_custom_tag")
def customTag(custom_tag_instance):
... 
return result
```

And in your template

```
{{ customTag|filter_of_custom_tag}}
```

Comment: I need more arguments

Comment: @marcelo.delta i found out a stackoverflow post regarding seems similar type of question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887536/how-to-pass-three-arguments-to-django-templatetags-filter). can you please check and tell is this solve your problem ?