# How to have two arguments in a django custom filter

Tags: python, django, django-custom-tags

I am trying to manipulate two objects for a calculation, however I am getting the error:"Invalid filter"

In the html frontend I have a nested loop with objects: units and person as following:

```
{{units|myFilter:person}}
```

where units has several objects and person only has one.

my filter is defined by:

```
def myFilter(units,person):
    n = 0
    for i in units:
        if i.name == person.name:
            n = n + 1
    return n
```

But is it not working, any ideas or suggestions please?

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add multiple arguments to my custom template filter in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat)

Comment: Also this can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887651/1079086)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a `simple_tag` function which accepts any number of positional or keyword arguments;

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def my_tag(a, b):
    print(a, b)

    return 'What you need'
```

And this is how to use it in your template;

```
{% my_tag 123 "abcd" %}
```

Here is the documentation; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason for `simple_tag` +1 for that